# How to reverse the order of dataframe in a pattern in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I want to reverse the following data frame in particular sequence.

```
Stage       Score 
W-3         25
W-3         2 Min 10 Sec
W-2         45
W-2         1 Min 34 Sec
W-1         75
W-1         1 Min 04 Sec
```

I want to reverse it in following order.

```
Stage       Score
W-1         75
W-1         1 Min 04 Sec
W-2         45
W-2         1 Min 34 Sec
W-3         25
W-3         2 Min 10 Sec
```

I'm using `df<- df[seq(dim(df)[1],1),]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R option using `order` + `ave`

```
df[with(df, order(Stage, ave(1:nrow(df), Stage, FUN = seq_along))), ]
```

which gives

```
  Stage        Score
5   W-1           75
6   W-1 1 Min 04 Sec
3   W-2           45
4   W-2 1 Min 34 Sec
1   W-3           25
2   W-3 2 Min 10 Sec
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Stage = c("W-3", "W-3", "W-2", "W-2", "W-1", "W-1"
), Score = c("25", "2 Min 10 Sec", "45", "1 Min 34 Sec", "75",
"1 Min 04 Sec")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `factor` with `levels` specified in the `rev`erse order of `unique` elements of 'Stage'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
    arrange(factor(as.character(Stage), 
             levels = rev(unique(as.character(Stage)))))
```

And the same with 'Date' column

```
df1 %>%
    arrange(factor(as.character(Date), 
             levels = rev(unique(as.character(Date)))))
```

-output

```
# Stage        Score       Date
#1   W-1 1 Min 04 Sec 2020-12-15
#2   W-1           75 2020-12-14
#3   W-2 1 Min 34 Sec 2020-12-13
#4   W-2           45 2020-12-12
#5   W-3 2 Min 10 Sec 2020-12-11
#6   W-3           25 2020-12-10
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df2 <- df1[order(factor(df1$Stage, levels = rev(unique(df1$Stage)))),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Stage = c("W-3", "W-3", "W-2", "W-2", "W-1", "W-1"
), Score = c("25", "2 Min 10 Sec", "45", "1 Min 34 Sec", "75", 
"1 Min 04 Sec"), Date = structure(18606:18611, class = "Date")),
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: the same is not working on date (yyyy-mm-dd) format.

Comment: @SophiaWilson can you wrap it in `as.character`. as the updated post

Comment: No luck on Date.

Comment: @SophiaWilson i updated the post.  It now works on both Date and alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `mixedorder` from `gtools`.

```
df <- data.frame("Stage" = c('W-3', 'W-3', 'W-2',
                             'W-2', 'W-1', 'W-1'),
                 "Score" = c(25, '2 Min 10 Sec', 45,
                             '1 Min 34 Sec', 75, '1 Min 04 Sec' ))

library(gtools)
df[mixedorder(df$Stage, decreasing = T), ]
```

---

```
  Stage        Score
5   W-1           75
6   W-1 1 Min 04 Sec
3   W-2           45
4   W-2 1 Min 34 Sec
1   W-3           25
2   W-3 2 Min 10 Sec
```